# Can macOS 13 Beta (macOS Ventura) work on a MacBook Pro 2015 so I can run Xcode?

Tags: macos, xcode, ventura, beta

I have an old MacBook Pro 2015 Early. I am running macOS 12.6.8 (Monterey) which I freshly installed. I want to install Xcode but it requires macOS version 13. macOS 13 is supported on MacBook Pro 2017. Is there a way to upgrade to macOS 13 Beta or do I have to buy a new MacBook?

Comment: You can install XCode on Monterey as well.

Comment: I'd be surprised if you can install the beta on your Mac. As far as I know, the beta has the same supported models as the release -- and not doing so would be very strange. As said, you should be able to install a version of Xcode that works on Monterey.

Comment: XCode 14.2 is the version supported on Monterey.  It can be downloaded from developer.apple.com.

Comment: Yes I have downloaded it and installed it just now. App store has latest Xcode 14.3.1 which requires macOS 13 and macOS 13 requires MacBook Pro 2017 at least. Mine is macBook Pro 2015. I am using it for react native development. Not sure I can build app later with Xcode 14.2 but currently I have my environment setup and I am good to go. Thanks for the help.